# Calculate duration based on conditons, while grouping but not aggregating

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**Objective:**

I have a dataset, df, that I would like to group by the ID and find the duration based on certain conditions: Focus == True, Read == True, and ID != "". However, I do not want to aggregate the IDs, as I wish to have them in their own separate 'chunks'

```
ID            Date                   Focus        Read


A             1/2/2020 5:00:00 AM    True         True
A             1/2/2020 5:00:05 AM    True         True
              1/3/2020 6:00:00 AM    True
              1/3/2020 6:00:05 AM    True         
B             1/4/2020 7:00:00 AM    True         True
B             1/4/2020 7:00:02 AM    True         True
B             1/4/2020 7:00:10 AM    True         True
A             1/2/2020 7:30:00 AM    True         True
A             1/2/2020 7:30:20 AM    True         True
```

**I would like this output:**

```
ID                          Duration               Date

A                           5 sec                  1/2/2020
B                           10 sec                 1/4/2020
A                           20 sec                 1/2/2020
```

**dput:**

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "A", "B"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/2/2020 5:00:00 AM", 
"1/2/2020 5:00:05 AM", "1/2/2020 7:30:00 AM", "1/2/2020 7:30:20 AM", 
"1/3/2020 6:00:00 AM", "1/3/2020 6:00:05 AM", "1/4/2020 7:00:00 AM", 
"1/4/2020 7:00:02 AM", "1/4/2020 7:00:10 AM"), class = "factor"), 
Focus = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "True ", class = "factor"), 
Read = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"True "), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

This works well, but instead of aggregating the IDs, how would I keep them separate:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(lubridate)
 df %>% 
 filter(as.logical(trimws(Read)), as.logical(trimws(Focus))) %>%
 mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(Duration = difftime(last(Date), first(Date), units = "secs"))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create the group with run-length-encoding-id `rleid` for adjacent non-equal elements in 'ID', and then apply the `difftime` on the 'Date' after conversion to `DateTime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
 filter(as.logical(trimws(Read)), as.logical(trimws(Focus))) %>%
 mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
 group_by(grp = rleid(ID), ID) %>%   
 summarise(Duration = difftime(last(Date), first(Date), units = "secs"),
         Date = as.Date(first(Date))) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  ID    Duration Date      
#  <fct> <drtn>   <date>    
#1 A      5 secs  2020-01-02
#2 B     10 secs  2020-01-04
#3 A     20 secs  2020-01-02
```

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: Hello @akrun, does rleid essentially create a consecutive list? or what is its function

Comment: @TanishaHudson it is based on whether the adjacent elements are same or not. i.e. `v1 <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'); rleid(v1)#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4` note that the first set of 'a's and the next set of 'a's are differently grouped

Comment: Hello is there a way to show the time as well in the output? m/d/y/ hh/mm/ss?

Comment: @TanishaHudson you can add `df %>% 
  filter(as.logical(trimws(Read)), as.logical(trimws(Focus))) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
  group_by(grp = rleid(ID), ID) %>%   
  summarise(Duration = difftime(last(Date), first(Date), units = "secs"), Datetime = format(first(Date), "%m/%d/%y %H/%M/%S"),
          Date = as.Date(first(Date))) %>% ungroup %>% select(-grp)`

Comment: Sorry @akrun, or maybe I have to create a new question. Is there a way to also add a threshold, if the Date column exceeds 4 min, create a break in time?

Comment: @TanishaHudson you meant after the `difftime`, then you can create an `mutate(grp2 = cumsum(as.numeric(Duration) > 4))`

Comment: Hello @Akrun, should I add this to the end?  mutate(grp2 = cumsum(as.numeric(Duration) > 4))

Comment: @TanishaHudson yes, you can add that